# Missing return type on function

Tags: typescript, react-select

I need to change the default text for dropdown, in react-select.
While using this - error msg is coming

`<Select placeholder="Select Country" noOptionsMessage={() => "please select list"} />`

`noOptionsMessage={() => "please select list"}`

*error  Missing return type on function  @typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type*

Comment: you can always disable eslint rules if you don't like them. This is not a compilation error it's just an error in code style

Comment: Yes, but if there is an option to resolve it. Then, better we should resolve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
<Select placeholder="Select Country" noOptionsMessage={():string => "please select list"} />
```

[Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html) you can find more information about typing functions in typescript